# Analogy of LC Circuit with lattice dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, electric-circuits

I don't understand why we're using an LC circuit, with the capacitors parallely connected, to study lattice dynamics. And then we get the same dispersion curve. What is the connection between an LC circuit and the atoms in a lattice? I've given both the circuit and the Dispersion curve drawm.
[image]

[image]

Comment: hint: $E=\frac12 \dot q^2-\frac12 q^2$.

Comment: Okay that gives the energy. So how does it go with the lattice? I still didnt understand. :(

Comment: the energy of *what*? [Spoiler: the lattice, for small displacements, behaves as a...]

Comment: Err...a linear chain?

Comment: Do you have only one type of capacitor and one type of inductance? and of How many are connected in which way? It would be helpful if you provided a clear idea of the circuit diagram. Also, in which way do you measure the supposed "dispersion"?

Comment: Thanks, this makes it clearer. I wonder how many LC's you are coupling and how you measure the dispersion ($k$ and $\omega$) in such a circuit.  The dispersion you  show is mass-spring  chains with two different springs?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot to mention. I've coupled 10 LC's. And I varied the frequency (or w) over a range and noted down the ones at which I got perfect ellipses or straight lines. Those occur at angles of multiples of pi/2. Then I plotted w against the angle of dispersion or (ka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that both the LC circuit and a lattice of atoms (in the limit of small displacements) are **harmonic oscillators**, and as such, they obey similar dynamics. You just change the symbols to go from one system to the other, but the equations of motion are formally the same.

Comment: Lol yes harmonic oscillators. Okay..so its just that. I thought there was some deeper significance. O.o

Comment: Can I ask one more thing?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: As I change the frequency of the input signal on the CRO, while working with the Lattice Dynamics Kit, the shapes on the screen alternate from circles/ellipses to short straight lines. Why do these shapes show? And it finally becomes a stout straight line which doesnt change further even after increasing the frequency. I understand thats the max freq applicable, but why those shapes...I mean I wanna know what's happening behind this. If you could refer any paper or book, that would also do. :)

Comment: What is a CRO and what is a Lattice Dynamics Kit?

Comment: Cathode Ray Oscilloscope. -_- You seriously didnt know? Or did I ask something crappy? -.-"

Comment: Lattice Dynamics kit comes as a readymade circuit consisting of parallel LC circuits in which we study the Dispersion Curve. -.-"

Comment: You are probably observing [Lissajous figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) due to the fact that the different inputs are out of phase (because of, e.g., the elements with reactance).

Comment: You have only one type of capacitor and one type of inductance and of these how many are connected in which way? It would be helpful if you provided a clear idea of the circuit diagram. Also, how do you measure the supposed "dispersion"?

Comment: Yes, I've added the circuit diagram and the curve, Charly.